# Linking against static `a` lib leads to 'undefined reference' when dynamic `so` lib does not

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I had to build ImageMagick from sources to get around a problem I was having. Having done that I can now compile my code with the new shared library, which incidentally is called `libMagick++-6.Q8.so`.  This I can do without a problem.

What I need is to be able to easily move the binary to other machines without having to rely on the (custom built) shared library, but building my code against the `libMagick++-6.Q8.a` file leads to numerous `undefined reference` linker errors.

Here's the relevant lines from my `Makefile`:

```
CXX= g++
CFLAGS= -DRENDER_TO_TEX -DUSEMAGICK -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8 -O2 -pthread 
LIBS= -L/opt/vc/lib -L/usr/lib -lbcm_host -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lstdc++ 
LIBS+= /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a /usr/lib/libboost_regex.a /usr/local/lib/libMagick++-6.Q8.a 
INCS= -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6

slideshow: slideshow.cpp $(OBJS) 
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) slideshow.cpp ${INCS} ${LIBS} ${OBJS} -o $@
```

Comment: `.so` have dependency list, so when you linking to it - you indirectly linking to other libraries too. `.a` don't have this - it is complete, you must specify all of required libraries.

Comment: @keltar, is there an easy way to figure out that list?

Comment: @Octopus Try looking at the headers to get an idea of what libraries it will try to link against.  Also us 'nm' with the binary that successfully linked to see which libraries it is using.

Comment: `ldd libname.so` will give you recursive list. `readelf` could be used for non-recursive lookup